# How can I adjust width of webview?

Tags: android

My code is affective when the user is accessing the pages by clicking a link.
But when the user press `Back Button` content won't fit :(

This is my current code for pressing `Back Button`

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
    WebView  myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.goBack();
}
```

How can I solve?

Comment: What is happening? What is the desired result?

Comment: @MarciCăşvan Desire result is that whole web content has to fit in window size. See my codes. It helps when jumping to next page by clicking a link on the web page. If I press `Back Button`, it bring me back to previous page. But whole web content won't fit in window:(

Comment: does the text wrap also ?

Comment: @MarciCăşvan what text are you talking about? web text? or my source text?

Comment: the text on the web page. if yes then maybe use this setting : webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL); but setUseWideViewPort(true); should work by default. maybe you are doing something wrong with your webview

Comment: @MarciCăşvan could you please put that as an answer?

Comment: @MarciCăşvan I haven't tried yet

Comment: @MarciCăşvan it says error with "LayoutAlgorithm"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35189/discussion-between-marci-csvan-and-husten)

Answer (score 1):

If your website text is being wrapped, use:

`webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL)` or

```
webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN)
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. but It says there's error with `LayoutAlgorithm`